# Почему на одних компьютерах работает ShellExecute и ShellExecuteEx, а на других нет?

Tags: delphi

Использовала ShellExecuteEx для вызова pdf документа. На моем компьютере работает нормально, но на работе (тот же Windows7) вызова нет. Как выяснить причину?
Марина.

Comment: В дополнение к ответам - в сторону антивируса гляньте, они любят шелл-подобные функции блокировать.

Comment: Вы правы. Блокировка идет антивирусными программами. Спасибо! Марина.

Comment: Спасибо всем, принявшим участие. Вопрос можно снять. Но использование CreateProcess с GetLastError я постараюсь освоить. С уважением, Марина.

Answer (score 1):

В случае ошибки вызова функции Windows API, ее часто можно узнать, вызвав в свою очередь функцию GetLastError. На C/C++ это делается так

```
LPVOID buffer;
DWORD error = GetLastError();

FormatMessage(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
    NULL,
    error,
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
    (LPTSTR) &buffer,
    0, NULL );

MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)buffer, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

LocalFree(buffer);
```

Список возможных ошибок указан в [описании MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762154(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую что-нибудь аналогичное для Delphi. Марина

Answer (score 1):

ShellExecute(Ex) - это довольно устаревшая функция. Лучше напрямую вызывать [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), тогда проблемы не совместимости можно будет избежать. Если всё таки вам нужно использовать именно ShellExecute, то воспользуйтесь [GetLastError](http://www.delphibasics.ru/GetLastError.php), смотрите на возвращаемый код и ищите его в списке, ссылку на который вам уже привели.

Comment: Спасибо за полезную ссылку. Постараюсь освоить увиденное! Марина

Answer (score 1):

ShellExecute(Ex) эквивалентен (кажется) двойному щелчку мыши по файлу в проводника, и если у вас нет ассоциированной с пдф-форматом программы, то есть не установлена какая-нибудь читалка пдф, то ShellExecute(Ex) ничего не сможет сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Запустите вашу программу с опцией "Run as Administrator"

Comment: Благодарю за быстрый отклик. Попробую! Марина